# Replace Text with jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little trouble getting this to work correctly.

I have breadcrumbs with the following structure

```
<nav class="breadcrumb" >
    <a href="http://example.com">Home</a>       
        ">"         
    <a href="http://example.com/category/Mens/">Mens</a>        
        "> Mens Clothing"       
</nav>
```

Which outputs to:

```
Home>Mens>Mens Clothing
```

I want:

```
Home>Mens>Clothing
```

And my code for replacing the last part of the breadcrumb:

```
$(".breadcrumb").text(function(){
    return $(this).text().replace("Mens Clothing", "Clothing");
})
```

My problem is that my code removes the links and just leaves me with"

```
<nav class="breadcrumb" >
    "Home>Mens>clothing"
</nav>
```

with no links.

Not sure why. Please help

Comment: Why don't you render it server side instead? If you don't want `"> Mens Clothing"`, why are you in first place setting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `html()` instead of `text()`:

```
$(".breadcrumb").html(function(){
    return $(this).html().replace("Mens Clothing", "Clothing");
});
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. I'll look up the difference between the two, though I can already kinda guess.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

With your current HTML, you could change your approach to

```
<nav class="breadcrumb" >
    <a href="http://example.com">Home</a>       
        ">"         
    <a href="http://example.com/category/Mens/">Mens</a>        
        "> <span data-last-crumb>Mens Clothing</span>"       
</nav>


$("[data-last-crumb]").text("Clothing");
```